# Direct Stdin To C Program

Tags: c

I have a file with the following in it.

```
Warrior 12, 60
Swordsman 39, 25
Orc 12, 13
```

The file name containing these, is called specs.

I'm trying to direct this to my C program. Like, specs | myprogram.c

Now for the question, how do I go through each item in the file, and add it to an array???

```
myArray = {Warrior, 12, 60, Swordsman, 39, 25, Orc, 12, 13}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should not only direct it, but read it in your program as well..

Comment: what solution are you asking for? it seems you would like to launch you program in shell? if so, it would be `cat specs | ./your_prog`. about the array thing, you need to learn about `struct`.

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you are asking.  In Bash, you can feed the contents of a file to a process via standard input as `./myprogram < input.txt`.  You cannot execute your C source code as you seem to be trying, though.  And for the C part, there is no such thing as an array of strings and integers in C.

Comment: Make an array of structs. You may have to allocate room for the string variables dynamically.

Comment: It looks like the right question here: How to read `stdin`? .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this-

```
 struct spec
{
  char specname[15]; //this can be char* also. Then you have to allocate suitably
  int data1;
  int data2;
};
struct spec specarr[100];
....
..
while(not end of input)
...
 scanf("%14s%d, %d",&specarr[i].specname,&specarr[i].data1,&specarr[i].data2);
```

I think this is what you want to do. Check it out.

Comment: Using format `"%14s%d ,%d" would be more useful and checking the result value of `scanf()` is critical.

Comment: @chux that will do also. But I considered the simplest one.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s...` vs. `scanf("%14s...` is like using `gets()` - a now eliminated part of C due to overrun issues.  Without some input limit, `scanf("%s...` is a weak programming practice as this style invites hacker attacks and gives C a poor reputation.

Comment: @chux Yes buffer overrun is really a glitch that may be exploited by hackers if one uses it. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Things you pipe to a program appear as its standard input and can be read with the normal means, in your case probably scanf.

Edit: Your array seems to contain multiple types which is hard to do in C -- I am under the impression that you are defining fighter classes with two attributes per line in your file, so you may want to define a structure for a class with a name field and two integer fields and what not, and then read your stdin and fill an array of these structs.

Edit2: Reading the comments I realized that I missed your missing `cat`. You can either say `cat file | program` or `program < file`; both will make the contents of *file* appear sequentially in the standard input of *program*. While the `cat` solution is more intuitive, at least for people who write left-to-right, the `<` solution is probably faster.

Comment: C noob here: shouldn't `scanf` be avoided and `fgets` be used instead?

Comment: And then you use sscanf anyway. I do not think much of that advice. If you read from unknown (and potentially malicious) sources you must guard against buffer overruns through long strings and maliciously crafted input in general, but that should not be your problem here (and can be done well in scanf proper).

Comment: Maybe the advice comes from problems with interactive programs, cf. http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/? Not your concern here. Interactive console programs are notoriously difficult to handle for the general case but unfortunately are among the first programs in programming classes, although they are rather  rare in the wild. Even in a linux console you probably meet only two most of the day, the shell and your editor. Everything else works on non-interactive pipes, argv or files.